# Pagination in Spring Boot via path variable - Requested path variable is not present in Controller request mapping annotations

Tags: java, spring-boot, pagination, request-mapping, path-variables

We are trying to do pagination with the help of this

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.kaczmarzyk</groupId>
    <artifactId>specification-arg-resolver</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

With request parameters its fine, but when we try with `Path variables` its giving exception saying

**Requested path variable {destUserId} is not present in Controller request mapping annotations**

The following are the methods we tried

**Method-1 : With @PathVariable**

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/cf/{destUserId}")
@ResponseBody
public PagedResponse<SystemStock> croudFundReport(@PathVariable(name = "destUserId") String eventId,
            @Conjunction (value = {
            @Or(value = @Spec(path = "metaType", params = {"meta_type"}, spec = Equal.class))},
            and = @Spec(path = "destUserId", pathVars = "destUserId", spec = Equal.class)) Specification<UserData> spec) {
        
        
    return null;
}
```

**Method-2 : Without @PathVariable**

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/cf/{destUserId}")
@ResponseBody
public PagedResponse<SystemStock> croudFundReport(@Conjunction (value = {
            @Or(value = @Spec(path = "metaType", params = {"meta_type"}, spec = Equal.class))},
            and = @Spec(path = "destUserId", pathVars = "destUserId", spec = Equal.class)) Specification<UserData> spec) {
        
        
    return null;
}
```

**Method-3 : RequestMapping with just path and with @PathVariable**

```
@RequestMapping("/cf/{destUserId}")
@ResponseBody
public PagedResponse<SystemStock> croudFundReport(@PathVariable(name = "destUserId") String eventId,
            @Conjunction (value = {
            @Or(value = @Spec(path = "metaType", params = {"meta_type"}, spec = Equal.class))},
            and = @Spec(path = "destUserId", pathVars = "destUserId", spec = Equal.class)) Specification<UserData> spec) {
        
        
    return null;
}
```

**Method-4 : RequestMapping with just path and without @PathVariable**

```
@RequestMapping("/cf/{destUserId}")
@ResponseBody
public PagedResponse<SystemStock> croudFundReport(@Conjunction (value = {
            @Or(value = @Spec(path = "metaType", params = {"meta_type"}, spec = Equal.class))},
            and = @Spec(path = "destUserId", pathVars = "destUserId", spec = Equal.class)) Specification<UserData> spec) {
        
        
    return null;
}
```

**Method-5 : RequestMapping with just path, without @PathVariable, without @Conjunction**

```
@RequestMapping("/cf/{destUserId}")
@ResponseBody
public PagedResponse<SystemStock> croudFundReport(@Spec(path = "destUserId", pathVars = "destUserId", spec = Equal.class) Specification<UserData> spec) {
        
    
    return null;
}
```

**Method-6 : GetMapping without @PathVariable, without @Conjunction**

```
@GetMapping(path = "/cf/{destUserId}", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@ResponseBody
public PagedResponse<SystemStock> croudFundReport(@Spec(path = "destUserId", pathVars = "destUserId", spec = Equal.class) Specification<UserData> spec) {
    
    
    return null;
}
```

**References**

1. [Path variable support](https://github.com/tkaczmarzyk/specification-arg-resolver)
2. [@PathVariable issue](https://github.com/tkaczmarzyk/specification-arg-resolver/issues/71)

The problem is we can access the `PathVariable` as a method argument, but when we try to specify it in that in `pathVars` in the above cases execution is not reaching our Controller and we are getting the same above exception. Any help?

Answer (score -1):

One thing I noticed you used GetMapping only in the last example. Is there reason for using RequestMapping?

Is there a specific reason to not use [JPA pagination][https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-pagination]?

Have you tried the following?

```
@GetMapping(path = "/cf/{destUserId}", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public PagedResponse<SystemStock> croudFundReport( @PathVariable(name = "destUserId") final String destUserId) {
 // TODO implementation
}
```

Comment: This is a basic GET API using Path Variable. I'm looking for pagination using annotations like **@Spec** and **@Conjunction**, the code you shared will work it works for me. The problem is when I specify that Path Variable in Spec